# Alpine js get original element in bind method

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Assuming I want to get the original element within the `Alpine.bind` method, how would I do that?
So I can retrieve properties like  $el.targetName,$el.style, $el.onclick etc
For example, if I have :

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.bind('SomeButton', () => ({
            type: 'button',
 
            '@click'() {
                // How would  i get the target element with ll its DOM properties
                //So I can retrive properties like  $el.targetName,$el.style, $el.onclick etc
            },
 

        }))
    })
</script>
```

I've tried `$el`, `this`(which only returns a js proxy) etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a component definition you have to prefix every object with `this.` to access the active instance of the component. So the solution is just to use `this.$el` to access the button HTML element:

```
<button x-data x-bind="SomeButton">Click here</button>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.bind('SomeButton', () => ({
      type: 'button',

      '@click'() {
          console.log(this.$el.textContent)
      },
  }))
})
</script>
```

This puts `Click here` in the console on click.

Note: don't forget to add `x-data` to the button if it does not have an Alpine.js parent element.